# sending asp.net forms data using $.post

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have an asp.net page Default1.aspx with 2 text fields and a button. I want to use $.post to pass data from Default1.aspx to Default2.aspx.

My question is how can i do that and then read the values in Default2.aspx?

Note ihave seen the serialize() method but cannot figure how to use it in asp.net context

Comment: Here's a good article on serialize. http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/472329.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Default1.aspx:

```
<input id="t1" />
<input id="t2" />
<button onclick="postData()">submit</button>

<script>
   function postData(){
      var t1 = $('#t1').val();
      var t2 = $('#t2').val();
      $.post('Default2.aspx',{text1:t1,text2:t2},function(result){
         //do something with the result
      });
   }
</script>
```

Default2.aspx:

PageLoad Event:

```
String t1 = Request["text1"]; //c#
String t2 = Request["text2"]; //c#

dim t1 as string = Request("text1") //vb
dim t2 as string = Request("text2") //vb
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do the post like you wish and then read the values in `Page_Load` of **Default2.aspx** using `PreviousPage.FindControl(...)` to get the value of ASP.NET controls you need. You might also want to check that `PreviousPage` is actually the **Default1.apsx** page...